how can I make the activity part of the bot's profile invisible when the bot is active?
client will look active, but I want that gray part of the place to look like the complete avatar of my bot
like that
i tried many ways to do that like ws and client presence options but it couldn't solve my problem
i found this maybe this could help for solving
https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1139294064886435924

As the answer you have linked suggests, you must use HTTP-only applications to achieve this. Discord.js does not support this, so you will need to use the discord-interactions package.
For context, Discord offers two ways to connect to their API in order to receive interactions:

Via WebSockets. Your client establishes a two-way connection to Discord. This is what the Discord client and discord.js does.
Via Webhooks(HTTP-Only). This is where you define a URL where you have hosted a HTTP server, and Discord sends interactions there as a HTTP request.

